# bayes / conditional probability question

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

The derivation of the conditional probabilities given in the solution puzzle me.

There are two identical boxes in front of you.
In box X, there are 3 white balls and 7 black balls.
In box Y, there are 7 white balls and 3 black balls.
You randomly reach one of the boxes and draw three balls from it one by one.
If every time you draw a ball you find it is white, at which of the following stages is the probability the highest that you chose box X?

```
(A) You drew one ball, and it was white.         
(B) You drew two balls, and they were both white.         
(C) You drew three balls, and they were all white.
```

[image]

Comment: When sampling more than one ball from a box, is sampling done with or without replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming draws w/o replacement based on the answers given, and I'll focus on the second question to form an example for others. Let $B$ be the chosen box ($x$ or $y$), the probability of selecting box $x$ in case we draw two white balls is as follows:

$$P(B=x|2W)=\frac{P(2W|B=x)P(B=x)}{P(2W|B=x)P(B=x)+P(2W|B=y)P(B=y)}$$

Here, $P(B=x)=P(B=y)=1/2$, so they cancel each other in numerator and denominator. And, $P(2W|B=x)$ is choosing two white balls when the box is $x$. There are two ways to think:

1. Probability of choosing the first balls as white, and then choosing the second ball as white, which is:

$$P(2W|B=x)=P(W_1|B=x)P(W_2|B=x,W_1)=\frac{3}{10}\times \frac{2}{9}$$

This way, we'll have $P(2W|B=y)=\frac{7}{10}\times\frac{6}{9}$, and therefore:
$$P(B=x|2W)=\frac{{3\over 10}\times{2\over 9}}{{3\over 10}\times{2\over 9}+{7\over 10}\times{6\over 9}}=\frac{1}{8}$$

2. There are ${3 \choose 2}$ ways to choose white balls from box $x$, and ${10\choose 2}$ ways to choose any two balls from it. So, the probability of choosing two white balls is ${3\choose 2}/{10\choose 2}$. This is similar for box $y$, with numerator being equal to ${7\choose 2}$ and the denominator is the same since we have 10 balls in it, too.

$$P(B=x|2W)=\frac{{3\choose 2}/{10 \choose 2}}{{3\choose 2}/{10 \choose 2}+{7\choose 2}/{10 \choose 2}}=\frac{{3\choose 2}}{{3\choose 2}+{7\choose 2}}=\frac{1}{8}$$